# How to redirect stdout in FastAPI docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, fastapi

I have an API for an Whisper AI model. This API starts the transcription for an audio file. When the transcription starts I wanted to get the progress bar on the frontend. I got this using following code.

```py
@app.websocket("/ws/transcribe")
async def transcribe_websocker(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ai.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
    
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break

        # Encode and send the line to the WebSocket client
        encoded_line = line.encode('utf-8')
        print(encoded_line)
        await websocket.send_text(encoded_line)

    # Close the process and the WebSocket connection
    process.stdout.close()
    process.wait()
    await websocket.close()
```

When I run this code in my windows machine using the command of `uvicorn main:app --reload` for development it works. It gives the output of the program progress bar as time goes on until the program is finished. I can show the progress bar on the frontend as it progresses.

But when I created a Docker container, the response now only sends the data all at once at the end, when the program is finished executed. Its doesn't send the response in between when the progress is ongoing.
The Dockerfile used:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /python-docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git -y

RUN pip3 install fastapi
RUN pip3 install "uvicorn[standard]"
RUN pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/jianfch/stable-ts.git
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN pip3 install moviepy
RUN pip3 install streaming_form_data
RUN pip3 install websockets

COPY . .

#COPYING MODELS
COPY base.pt /root/.cache/whisper/base.pt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Comment: Set an environment variable `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`.

Comment: The Docker log files are line-buffered, meaning they won't update until a newline is received. It prevents some progress bars from working as intended. If you reattach to the container you should be able to see it properly.